how can i add a new select file button with react?
const Selectfile = () => {
  const handleFileSelect = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    const fileInput = document.createElement('input');
    fileInput.type = 'file';
    fileInput.accept = 'image/*';
    fileInput.onchange = handleFileChange;
    fileInput.click();
  };

  const handleFileChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const selectedFile = event.target.files?.[0];
    if (selectedFile) {
      console.log('Selected file:', selectedFile);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button className="selectFileButton" onClick={handleFileSelect}>
        Select File
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

Type '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: Event) => any'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'ev' are incompatible.
    Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>': nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist

how can I add a new select file function button in the chatbot with JS/ react?

You cannot bind a React event handler to a native on* event property. Why do you need to programmatically create an <input type="file"> element anyway? Can you not simply add one in your JSX / HTML?

Does this answer your question? jQuery trigger file input (ignore the jQuery part, there's plenty of plain JS / CSS answers there)

Keep in mind that programatically creating element is a very bad practice in react, as reat uses a virtual DOM . Element inserted manually will not be part of react virtual dom and can lead you to unexpected behaviour

Use <label> instead. Label provide htmlFor attribute to target to your input element when u interact with this label. So u just need to style your label, and hide this input.
<label htmlFor="input-id">
    <input type="file" hidden id="input-id" onChange={handleFileChange } />
</label>

